# List of URL Views / Templates for User in Lift Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, lift

Im trying to show a list of views for the logged in user. The list consists of the db entities for the user which i can retrieve from them db. Im trying to bind the correct address to the current view. What i would like is a list of views (urls) in the format:

> www.mywebsite.com/result?id=105/myTitle

I know I can use SHtml.link but can anyone suggest how I can achieve the desired url? My code is below:

```
myUserResults.flatMap{userResult =>
   Helpers.bind("result", xhtml,
     "id" -> userResult.id,
      "title" -> userResult.title,
      "link" -> {SHtml.link("/result?id="+ userResult.id + "/" +userResult.title) }
      )
```

Comment: Anyone suggest how I can achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out. A Request var is needed:

```
"link" -> {SHtml.link("/result?id="+ userResult.id + "/" +userResult.title, myRequestVar(userResult), Text("Result"))}
```